# Writing and reading namedtuple into a file in python

Tags: python, json, file-io, pickle, namedtuple

I need to write a data structure stored as `namedtuple` to file and read it back as a `namedtuple` in python.

Solutions here suggest using `Json.load`/`loads` or `pickle` which write the variable as json key-value pair in the form of strings. However, all my field accesses/dereferences are of the form `struct.key` (rather than `struct["key"]` which is the way to access json values), and it is unfeasible to correct this in the whole code.

I want to store this to a file because the struct is huge and takes a lot of time to generate.

Comment: Pickle has nothing to do with json. If you pickle a namedtuple object to a file you'll be able to read it back from the file as a namedtuple as well.

Comment: As @sebastian has mentioned - using `pickle` is going to be the simplest - if you really wanted JSON (maybe so it's human readable/editable) then you can round-trip a `namedtuple` but it's more resource intensive to do so.

Comment: group_t= namedtuple('group','field1, field2') ; Myobj = group_t(field1=val1,field2=val2) I get a can't pickle < class '__main__.group'> it's not found as __main__.group.

Answer (score 20):

Since the standard JSON modules in Python generally use `dict` to work with JSON objects, you need to convert to and from a `dict`.

For a little setup, let's say I've created this `namedtuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> import json
>>> X = namedtuple('X', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> x = X(1,2,3)
>>> x
X(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

1. Use `_asdict()` to convert to a `dict` that you can dump as JSON:

   ```
   >>> j = json.dumps(x._asdict())
   >>> j
   '{"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}'
   ```

   Now you have a JSON representation.
2. To get it back into an object, use `**` to convert a `dict` into keyword arguments:

   ```
   >>> x2 = X(**json.loads(j))
   >>> x2
   X(x=1, y=2, z=3)
   ```

   Done.

You can of course read/write that JSON out to a file any way you wish. (For example, the JSON modules have methods that work with files directly.)

Comment: Thanks, I suddenly understand how the **kwargs works now :-)

Answer (score 12):

Just addressing your pickling difficulty, it seems that for `pickle.dumps()` to work it is required that the `typename` argument to `namedtuple` match the name to which the returned class is bound.

```
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

group_t = namedtuple('group_t', 'field1, field2')
Myobj = group_t(field1=1, field2=2)

>>> pickle.dumps(Myobj)
'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\ngroup_t\np1\nc__builtin__\ntuple\np2\n(I1\nI2\ntp3\ntp4\nRp5\n.'
```

Compare with this:

```
mismatched_group_t = namedtuple('group_t', 'field1, field2')
Myobj = mismatched_group_t(field1=1, field2=2)
>>> pickle.dumps(Myobj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.group_t'>: it's not found as __main__.group_t
```

The difference between the two classes is:

```
>>> group_t.__name__
'group_t'
>>> mismatched_group_t.__name__
'group_t'
```

I'd say that that's what is throwing `pickle` off.

Comment: It looks like `pickle` is trying to access the class in the current scope. What would happen if a method returned a `namedtuple` and the class was defined elsewhere and not imported, or maybe [not even stored anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17921869/1394393)?

Comment: @LtWorf: what wouldn't work? What are you referring to?

Comment: jpmc26's solution

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for doing this: https://github.com/ltworf/typedload

It supports rather complicated types, which include enums, unions, tuples, sets, lists.

```
import typedload
typedload.dump(some_namedtuple)
```

Your namedtuple could be something more complicated like this

```
class B(NamedTuple):
    name: str
class A(NamedTuple):
    values: List[Union[str, int]]
    other: Dict[str, str]
    points: Tuple[Tuple[float, float, float], ...]
    more: Optional[B] = None
```

And it can do `dump` of objects and then `load` them back.

Comment: Just FYI since I'm pretty sure you assumed otherwise, I never voted on this answer nor raised any flags against it. The only flag I raised on it was to request undeletion after your edit.