# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main___.{CONST} '>: attribute lookupfaileddir_namesmain_on __main__ failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, namedtuple

firstly `dir_names` works well when pickling

```
dir_names = collections.namedtuple('dir_names', ['mark', 'category'])
pickle.dump(dir_names, open('tmp.bin', 'wb'))
```

I want make `dir_name` a const

```
DIR_NAMES = collections.namedtuple('dir_names', ['mark', 'category'])
pickle.dump(DIR_NAMES, open('tmp.bin', 'wb'))
```

but when pickling it, i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zyq/CC_Cat/warc_process.py", line 376, in <module>
    pickle.dump(DIR_NAMES, open('tmp.bin', 'wb'))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.dir_names'>: attribute lookup dir_names on __main__ failed
```

I wonder why it's goes bad when being a const, and why `DIR_NAMES` been lowerwised at `__main__.dir_names`

I tried `defaultdict` works well

> ```
> DD = collections.defaultdict(int)
> pickle.dump(DD, open('tmp.bin', 'wb'))
> ```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: using uppercase name `DIR_NAMES` shouldn't create constant

Comment: it seems it needs the same name in `namedtuple("DIR_NAMES", ...)`  as variable `DIR_NAMES = ...`

Comment: but why `DIR_NAMES` been lowercased at traceback, got me confused

Comment: `traceback` shows name from `namedtuple('dir_names'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `pickle` needs eexactly the same name in `namedtuple("DIR_NAMES", ...)` as in variable `DIR_NAMES = ...`

```
DIR_NAMES = collections.namedtuple('DIR_NAMES', ['mark', 'category'])
pickle.dump(DIR_NAMES, open('tmp.bin', 'wb'))
```

---

You can see this problem also in answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707755/1832058
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28149627/1832058

Comment: got it, thx, not even thinking of it